# How to make webpack-dev-server serve my index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to get an extremely simple bare-bones TypeScript project setup with Webpack and I'm having an incredibly hard time for some reason.

I followed [this](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/) guide and everything is working. When I simply run `webpack` my files will bundle and compile and be outputted into the `dist` directory. From there I can host them on a local server and it all works fine.

However, I want to avoid having to manually bundle and compile my code every single time I make a change, and I'd like for this to be done automatically each time I save my files. As far as I can tell this is a common use for Webpack and so I'm not sure why I'm having such an incredibly hard time finding any good information on it.

I decided to use the webpack dev server to accomplish this, so I read [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) tutorial and for the life of me I can't find anybody who explains how to get it to also server my `index.html`? When I run `webpack serve --mode=development` all goes well, and when I navigate to the localhost port that I server to I get a 404 error.

One of the "tips" on the previously linked page reads

> If you're having trouble, navigating to the `/webpack-dev-server` route will show where files are served. For example, http://localhost:9000/webpack-dev-server.

When I navigate to `localhost:1234/webpack-dev-server` it tells me that it's only serving a single file: `bundle.js` Clearly a JavaScript file alone is not going to work, and I need it to also serve the `index.html` file that's in my `dist` directory.

Now, my knowledge here is very limited as this is my first time working with Webpack, but here's all the detail I can give and hopefully it's not accidentally totally unrelated:

Whenever my dev server reloads itself (whenever it's booted up or if a watched file changes while it's running) it only updates the `bundle.js` file *that it's serving.* It doesn't update the `bundle.js` file stored in my `dist` directory on my hard drive. How can I make it update both?

And also, how do I make the server also serve my `index.html` file instead of only the `bundle.js`? Where is it even getting that `bundle.js` from? Is it compiling all of my code from scratch to create that js file or is it taking that out of the `dist` directory?

And additionally, am I going about this totally in the wrong way? Where should my `index.html` even go? I put my TypeScript files into a `src` directory and they're converted to `.js` files and moved into my `dist` directory... Should I also put my `index.html` inside `src` or does it belong in `dist` or somewhere else entirely? When I put `index.html` in `src` it doesn't get copied over into `dist`, it just ignores it completely. If my `index.html` file doesn't belong in `src` it must belong in `dist`, but if it belongs in `dist` then how can I expect the dev server to find it and serve it along with the other TypeScript files in `src`? Why can't the dev server just serve everything in `dist` and automatically compile everything from `src` into `dist`? I must be misunderstanding the flow of it all, but I have no idea where to look for an explanation and I've been at this for several hours now.

Just a general explanation of how it all works would be very helpful as well, as I can't find a single article or forum post anywhere that details all the spaghetti going on with Webpack. I've been avoiding bundlers and all this NPM mess for as long as I can because I constantly run into issues like this, but I finally decided to jump in and just push through all the mess and I'm already regretting it. If someone could just point me (and other people having similar problems) to some good resources for learning about all the automagic going on that would be *hugely* appreciated. The Webpack documentation and guides are very much worthless to a newbie.

My Webpack config file:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.ts",
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    devServer: {
        compress: false,
        static: false,
        client: {
            logging: "warn",
            overlay: {
                errors: true,
                warnings: false
            },
            progress: true
        },
        port: 1234, host: "0.0.0.0"
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your entry set in webpack? So that it is included?

```
    entry: {
      main: 'path/to/index.ts'
    },
```

You could also try adding to your index.ts file

```
require('file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!../index.html');
```

Or

```
require("./src/index.html");

// Then In your webpack config file add a loader

loaders : {   { test: /\.html/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]' } }
```

Otherwise you could always copy this file over with webpack copy plugin

```
{
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html'
    })
  ]
}
```

will need to run `npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin` to install it. As well as move your index.html file into your src folder

Comment: No. I have my `main.ts` file marked as the entry point. When I pass in my `index.html` as the entry point instead I get a Webpack error telling me that I haven't told Webpack how to handle html files. `"You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file."`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will mark it as accepted, as using the copy plugin is what ended up working for me. One final question though: Is using the copy plugin really the best method here? It seems to mess with quite a few things and apply quite a few limitations which I don't particularly enjoy. It's my best bet for now, but is it really the best (only?) solution moving forward?

Comment: I think you should be able to add it as a require in your index file. Maybe instead of using the loader try. `require("./index.html");` But then you would need to add a loader into your webpack config like this. `loaders : {
  { test: /\.html/, loader: 'file?name=[name].[ext]' }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Please visit `localhost:1234/bundle` (Where `bundle.js` is your bundled file) the [`magichHTML` route](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devservermagichtml), which will load the HTML file with the bundled script.

Comment: Visiting `localhost:1234/bundle` DOES give me an HTML file with my code imported and running, however, said HTML file is not the HTML file that I wrote, and it doesn't contain any of my desired elements, leading my `document.getElementById()` calls to return null. The console fills with errors. The HTML file located there is empty, only containing `<script>` tag imports of my code. All my HTML elements are missing